# Cat swollen eyes, freckles on eyelid, how to treat it?

Tags: cats, eye-disease

[image: eye]
My cat suddenly started to avoid sunlight. His eyes are swollen, and I noticed a brown freckles on his 3rd eyelid. He is an indoor cat. I didn't notice anything else. What is that? How do I treat it?

Comment: can you please add a bit more information to your question like the age of your cat how long has it been like this and where you live,it is possible that somebody here can answer your question and tell you what it might be but you will have to take your cat to a vet for diagnose and treatment.it does not look infected so it is not an emergency but keep an eye on it for a few days and call your vet for advice.

Comment: 2 years old, cat lives indoor in UK, he had that for 2 days

Comment: The amount of brown pigmentation I see on the third eyelid is normal. If you noticed additional freckles that aren't visible in the image, that would indeed be unusual. In any case, this amount of swelling warrants a trip to the vet. The fact that your cat avoids sunlight is a strong indication that his eye causes him pain or at least great discomfort. You should not try any home remedies without knowing what actually caused this.